# Dialog results after choose from lists

Tags: applescript

I have written a script for school that opens folders and ebooks for selected subjects. You type the subject you want to access, then it opens the folder of that subject for you (in the resources folder of the app). However, some subjects have ebooks, so I've made the script show a `choose from list` if the subject does have one. This works well, and I can do both results from choose from list, so that works. It's when I get up to subjects without an ebook (so they don't require a `choose from list`) that it does't work. Say, for example, Drama doesn't have an ebook, so if I type "drama" it'll just open the folder straight away. This is what I have so far; can anyone tell me why it doesn't work?:

```
set subjectsWithEbook to {"History", "Science", "Maths", "French"}

display dialog "What subject would you like to access?" default answer ""
set theSubject to text returned of the result

if theSubject is in subjectsWithEbook then
choose from list {"Open folder", "Open eBook"} with prompt "What to open?"
set theResult to item 1 of the result
if theResult is "Open eBook" and theSubject is "history" then
    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        open location ""
    end tell
else
    if theResult is "Open folder" and theSubject is "history" then
        tell application "Finder" to open folder ((path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Subjects:History")
    else
        if theResult is "Open eBook" and theSubject is "science" then
            tell application "Safari"
                activate
                open location ""
            end tell
        else
            if theResult is "Open folder" and theSubject is "science" then
                tell application "Finder" to open folder ((path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Subjects:Science")
            else
                if theResult is "Open eBook" and theSubject is "french" then
                    tell application "Safari"
                        activate
                        open location ""
                    end tell
                else
                    if theResult is "Open folder" and theSubject is "french" then
                        tell application "Finder" to open folder ((path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Subjects:French")
                    else
                        if theResult is "Open eBook" and theSubject is "maths" then
                            tell application "Preview" to open (path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:maths_ebook.pdf"
                        else
                            if theResult is "Open folder" and theSubject is "maths" then
                                tell application "Finder" to open folder ((path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Subjects:Maths")
                            else
                                if theSubject contains "Drama" then
                                    tell application "Finder" to open folder ((path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Subjects:Drama")
                                end if
                            end if
                        end if
                    end if
                end if
            end if
        end if
    end if
end if
end if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accommodate with all your cases, and even more, I updated my first script, using the records data structure as explained before.

You can now define as many subjects you want, and for each, the folder to open (if any), or the ebook. For the ebook, you can also define the application to be used to open: for instance, it could be "Preview" for a PDF file, or Safari if the ebook record contains URL.

In my exemple, I added, for Drama, a txt file which must the open via TextEdit.

For Maths this is a pdf to be opened via Preview

For History, this is an URL (google !) to be open via Safari.

This is just to show you that you can do anything with this new script.
(I have added many comments)

```
(* each record contains 4 values : there are as many records as you need
  Sub : the name of the subject
  EB  : the URL or filename of the ebook. if empty no ebook
  Fol : the name of the folder from Contents/Resources to be open. if empty,no folder to open
  EBApp : the application to be used to open EB. 
          In this exemple Maths uses "Preview", Drama uses texEdit and all others are using Safari
*)
global myRules -- to be use also in sub-routines

-- fill here all your definitions URLs and documents
set myRules to {{Sub:"Maths", EB:"maths_ebook.pdf", Fol:"Maths", EBApp:"Preview"}, {Sub:"History", EB:"www.google.com", Fol:"History", EBApp:"Safari"}}
set myRules to myRules & {{Sub:"Science", EB:"myURL", Fol:"Maths", EBApp:"Safari"}, {Sub:"French", EB:"www.apple.com", Fol:"French", EBApp:"Safari"}}
set myRules to myRules & {{Sub:"Drama", EB:"Drama.txt", Fol:"", EBApp:"TextEdit"}}


set R to display dialog "What subject would you like to access?" default answer "" buttons {"Open folder", "Open ebook", "Cancel"}
set theSubject to Capital(text returned of R) -- make sure 1 letter capital like in subjectsWithEbook
set theChoice to (button returned of R)
set NumItem to ItemList(theSubject)

if NumItem is 0 then -- don't know what to do with this subject not in the list !
display alert "Sorry; Subject " & theSubject & " is not available"
return
end if

set mySubject to item NumItem of myRules
if (theChoice is "Open folder") and (Fol of mySubject is not "") then
tell application "Finder" to open folder ((path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Subjects:" & (Fol of mySubject))
end if

if (theChoice is "Open ebook") and (EB of mySubject is "") then
display alert "Sorry; Subject " & theSubject & " has no ebook version available"
return
end if

if (theChoice is "Open ebook") and (EB of mySubject is not "") and (EBApp of mySubject is not "") then
if EBApp of mySubject is "Safari" then
    tell application "Safari" to open location (EB of mySubject)
else
    tell application (EBApp of mySubject) to open (EB of mySubject)
end if
end if

on ItemList(LSubject) -- return the item number of the subject in myRules
set LItem to 0
repeat with I from 1 to (count of myRules)
    if LSubject = Sub of item I of myRules then set LItem to I
end repeat
return LItem
end ItemList

on Capital(Localtext) -- set 1st letter in capital and other small caps.
set Letters to every character of Localtext
repeat with I from 1 to count of Letters
    set A to ASCII number of (item I of Letters)
    if (I = 1) and (A > 96) and (A < 123) then set A to A - 32
    if (I > 1) and (A > 64) and (A < 91) then set A to A + 32
    set item I of Letters to ASCII character of A
end repeat
return Letters as string
end Capital
```

Comment: Yeah... but the URL's for each ebook is different; I just took them out for security reasons. Good script though

Comment: then, one more reason to use records with folder and URL per category.

Comment: I just updated the complete script. See my first answer. it should not fit all your requirements

Comment: That's really clever. Got any ideas on how to add an error box if the subject doesn't have an ebook? Thanks

Comment: Thanks so much mate. This has opened a new way of apple scripting for me. :)